# Ansible template with_items conflict

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I want to use a template to create config files in /etc/network/interfaces.d/

But I got an error when I use with_items in a template task...

I'm not sure for the ansible_host.networks in with_items.

Thanks !

Inventory.yml :

```
proxmoxve: # group
      hosts:
        virtu:
          networks: 
            internet: 
              interface: enp9s0
              mode: manual
              type: interface
            openvswitch:
              interface: vmbr1
              mode: static
              type: ovs_bridge
        sauv: 
          networks: 
            internet: 
              interface: enp38s0
              mode: manual
              type: interface
            openvswitch:
              interface: vmbr1
              mode: static
              type: ovs_bridge
```

Playbook.yml :

```
---
- hosts: proxmoxve
  tasks:
  - name: "Install openvswitch with fresh cache"
    apt: 
      name: openvswitch-switch
      state: present
      update_cache: yes

  - name: "Set internet interfaces"
    template: 
      src: templates/interfaces.j2
      dest: "/etc/network.interfaces.d/{{ item.interface }}"
    whith_items: "{{ ansible_host.networks }}"
```

Error :

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: template, whith_items

The error appears to be in '/home/yanux/dev/ansible-proxmoxve/proxmoxve_config_networks.yml': line 10, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


  - name: "Set internet interface to manual"
    ^ here
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo: `whith_items` should be `with_items`.